# emacs ivy always selecting default function

Tags: ivy

I just started trying out ivy. I took the following example from the ivy tutorial:

```
(defun my-action-1 (x)
  (message "action-1: %s" x))

(defun my-action-2 (x)
  (message "action-2: %s" x))

(defun my-action-3 (x)
  (message "action-3: %s" x))

(defun mih ()
  (interactive)
  (ivy-read "test: " '("foo" "bar" "baz")
            :action '(1
                      ("o" my-action-1 "action 1")
                      ("j" my-action-2 "action 2")
                      ("k" my-action-3 "action 3"))))
```

My problem is, no matter which option I select, only the default function is invoked. Say, I selected option "j" above, I still the message:

```
"action-1 bar"
```

My expectation was that I would get:

```
"action-2 bar"
```

Since I did not make *any* changes to the code from the tutorial, I think I am missing something here.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't get a definitive answer here, maybe ask the Ivy maintainer. It's possible that the tutorial has a bug or is unclear.

Comment: Tried your code, works as it should. `M-x mih`, select foo, `M-o k`, messages `action-3: foo`.

Comment: I agree with @Hubisan, things seem to work here. Evaluate everything again. If it still doesn't work, please give us the exact steps to reproduce.